# how to avoid set precision for the components of an array?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have an array a with 9 components and when i set precision for this array, components of a also get the precision.however, i want to avoid that and only the number get the precision. for instance, a[1,1]+2.000000000000000 and so on. is there anyway i can do that?

```
a:=Array[a1,{3,3}]+2
SetPrecision[a,16]
```

Comment: Use `SetAttributes[a1, NHoldAll]` to prevent arguments of `a1` from getting numericized.

Comment: @CarlWoll sorry i could not find that page earlier and thanks it solved my problem.

Comment: It helps that I knew to search for `NHoldAll`.